# Descargar un modelo de mongo con NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, zip, model

Tengo una base de datos de Mongo y me gustaría, mediante una API en Node, poder descargarme en zip esos registros, en un CSV o en el formato que sea. Ahora mismo tengo 501426 registros por lo que el find del modelo me da el siguiente error al obtener todos los registros:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[15092:000001FE5E775B70]    95966 ms: Mark-sweep 1407.6 (1467.7) -> 1407.5 
(1451.2) MB, 1408.9 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[15092:000001FE5E775B70]    97421 ms: Mark-sweep 1407.5 (1451.2) -> 1407.5 
(1451.2) MB, 1454.2 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000003F5F89A5EE1 <JSObject>
2: GetHash(aka GetHash) [native collection.js:1] [bytecode=000003F5F89D1721 
offset=51](this=0000011364082311 <undefined>,o=000002F6E28FAE89 <JSFunction  
wrapper (sfi = 000003167E337821)>)
4: set [native weak-collection.js:1] [bytecode=000003167E3380F9 offset=50]
(this=000001DB08591699 <JSWeakMap>,key=000002F6E28FAE89 <JSFunction wrapper 
(sfi = 000003167E337821)>,value=00000021B54F67F9 <J...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of 
memory
```

Entiendo que son muchos registros y no es capaz de procesas todos, pero habría alguna manera? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba enviar los datos por streaming desde mongodb:

```
collection 
    .find() 
    .stream() 
    .pipe(res)
```

Mas info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29578947/9209251